# Rails - updating a User leads to an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I want to update an user in User table on the page and then when it's done, redirect to that user's page.
Whenever I do this, I get this error:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<p>
<%= @user.name %>
</p>
```

This is how my update looks like:

```
def update
@user = User.find(params[:id])
if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
flash[:success] = "Update successful"
redirect_to @user
else
render 'edit'
end
end
```

The page I redirect to:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<p>
    <%= @user.name %>
</p>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Will provide more info if needed.

Edit:

Show action:

```
def show
    if signed_in?
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
```

Comment: Please show your `show` action code.

Comment: Edited first post with it.

Comment: Might it be that updating the user logs it out? Because it makes the changes to database but it just does not redirect - it produces an error instead.

Comment: could you be more specific. what is the template that is rendered? what is the action that gets called in your controller?

Comment: Fixed the problem by just adding another sign_in before the update redirects.  I have no idea why update logs the user out tough.